Establishing WebRTC peer connection using existing connection tunnel
I have two WebRTC clients separated by rather complex network configuration. In time when connection between these clients can be established I have some sort of connection tunnel (supporting both TCP and UDP protocols) between two endpoints easily accessible for clients: let's say "client 1" can connect to "endpoint 1", and "client 2" can connect to "endpoint 2", and after connection they will get direct connection for each other.
As far as I know, the work for pointing "endpoint 1" for "client 1" and "endpoint 2" for "client 2" lays on STUN server, that simply returns "endpoint 1" address for "client 2" address request and vice versa.
But my question is - can I make RTCPeerConnection without using STUN server, just providing IP addresses of endpoints for both clients? Because supporting STUN server seems a bit of an overhead for this simple task.
